# How to calculate sum of night light radiance for each feature in a feature collection?

Tags: zonal-statistics, grouping, reducers, night-time-images, reduceregion

I have a shapefile which contains 36 polygons (districts/counties).  For each district, I want to calculate sum of lights (as well as count total number of pixels). I tried following code but failed.  May someone please guide what could be solution?
https://code.earthengine.google.com/a4e80f2b80d4a67e46edbdb9f4f7c8a0

```
var nighttime  = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG")
.filterDate("2016-01-01","2019-12-31")
.select('avg_rad');

var NL_median = ee.Image(nighttime.median());
print(NL_median);

var scale = NL_median.projection().nominalScale();

var district_sum = NL_median.reduceRegions({
  collection :roi, 
  reducer :ee.Reducer.sum(), scale :scale});

var district_count = NL_median.reduceRegions({
  collection :roi, 
  reducer :ee.Reducer.count(), scale :scale});
```